# Scalatest: how to check if a collection contains element that satisfies certain criteria

Tags: scala, scalatest, matcher

Say I have a list of books:

```
val books = List(
    Book(title="Foo", year=2014),
    Book(title="Bar", year=2014))
```

How to check with a single expression if collection `books` is not empty and only contains books published in 2014?

Comment: Found a very similar question here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6997939/using-a-havepropertymatcher-for-collection-elements-in-scalatest

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using [`matchers`](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_matchers):

```
books should not be empty
books.map(_.year) should contain only (2014)
```

Or just:

```
books.map(_.year) should contain only (2014)
```

since this check asserts that the list is not empty.

Comment: Forgot to mention in the question - I want to do it with a single matching expression. In other words I need to have a Matcher instance that does this check. It's easy to achieve it with two `should`, but how would I combine them in one?

Comment: Why would you do that? Check each assertion independently.

Comment: The second check does what you want: if the list only contains books that are in 2014, then it is not empty.

Comment: I want to compose a single Matcher that would inspect a given collection in all the different ways. Non-empty check is just an example. The idea is to find a way how to compose matchers via `and` and `or` having one matcher to check the collection properties (e.g. collection size) while another matcher checks collection element. I tried to use `have` matcher in this way - `book should (have size 1 and contain(have (...)))`, but that didn't work

Comment: Maybe a custom matcher is what you are after? http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_matchers#usingCustomMatchers

Comment: Seems so. Just thought it would possible with standard matchers. Apparently not.

Comment: Isn't composition of matchers (manual: http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_matchers#creatingMatchersUsingLogicalOperators ) what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

There is a purposely built `scalatest` class called `LoneElement`:

https://www.scalatest.org/scaladoc/3.0.8/org/scalatest/LoneElement.html

```scala
import org.scalatest.LoneElement.convertToCollectionLoneElementWrapper

books.loneElement.year shouldBe 2014
```